# Updating rails model objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json

Okay.

Google API gives you the javascript for the Google Plus signup/login button.

```
 function signinCallback(authResult) {
  if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
// Update the app to reflect a signed in user
// Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
} else {
// Update the app to reflect a signed out user
// Possible error values:
//   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
//   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
//   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
 }
}
```

IF a user successfully logs in with Google Plus, I want to use the form attributes/variables to create a new user. A user has a username and a password. The Google Plus login gives the google plus user a fullname and a gplus id. I want to create a user in the database with a username equal to their gplus fullname and a password equal to their gplus id. How would I go about using ruby with my javascript to save them to the model. I reviewed [this link](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Section four seems to be the right direction. I'm just having trouble grasping it.

If you think there would be a better way to do this. Please let me know! I read up on Devise with google plus, but it seemed too risky to implement during a time crunch. I might try it anyway depending on how long this takes me.